# Access host physical drive from VM with orignal drive letter, not UNC path

Tags: vmware-player, windows-7, virtualization

I virtualized an existing Windows XP partition using VMWare Converter, and I am running it from within a Windows 7 host. The original system had XP on drive C: and a large data drive on D: (too large to virtualize).

From within VMware Player (before starting the VM), I go to Virtual Machine Settings, Hardware tab. I click Add and add a new hard disk. The wizard steps are "Add Hard Disk", "Use A Physical Disk", select physical drive and individual partition, then check the partition corresponding to the desired D: drive.

After making these changes and attempting to start the VM, VMWare player gives an error about not being able to connect, and then hangs.

I also tried a different approach using Shared Folders. Under the Virtual Machine Settings, Options tab, "Shared Folders" lets me map the D: Drive as a shared folder, but from withing the VM, it appears as a network resource, with a UNC path like "\VMware\long\unc\path". Unfortunately, programs that are expecting D:\ will not work with that.

What is the procedure to access a host drive and map it as a physical drive letter from VMWare player?

Answer (score 2):

After further searching with various keywords combinations, I came across [this article:](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1046)

The key phrase is:

> You can map a shared folder to a drive
>   letter just as you would with a
>   network share.

How to get your "other" drive to appear with the proper letter -

1. From the VMWare Player menu: VM /
   Settings / Options Tab / Shared
   Folders.
2. Click Add and enter the
       drive lettter (D:) as the host
       path. Enable the share.
3. From a Windows Explorer Window in
   the guest OS, map the desired drive letter to
           the VMWare share. It will appear in
           the Network tree as a new level
           called "VMware Shared Folders" below
           "Microsoft Windows Network".

Comment: A few years later (2018), in a Linux guest OS shared folders are automatically mounted under /mnt/hgfs